# // Formatting java source comments --------------------------------

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, comments

I use, and have seen used, a separator-comment in Java and C code along the lines of:

```
// fields used in configuration ---------------------------
int a = 0; 
etc

// fields used for authentication process -----------------
String principalID = "";
etc
```

It helps with readability (IMO anyway) and refactoring.  I used-to use jalopy to extend the ---- to the end of the line, but it seems to have fallen by the wayside in recent years, and I can't find how to configure eclipse to do it.

Does anyone have a process or plugin they use (I'm using java so eclipse config would be ideal, but I'll use another tool if necessary), before I write a sed script to do it? (no sense re-inventing the wheel!).

Comment: That style of comment is a very bad idea. It adds nothing but clutter, it is not a Javadoc, you need to fiddle around with it every time you add or remove a single letter, you can't write more than a line in that style. I hope no one wastes time on writing a plugin for such or adds code that has to be maintained to the Eclipse code base that does this.

Comment: If a series of dashes truly does add to the readability of something why don't poems, books and literature all have a series of dashes added to the ends of lines. Looks to me like you've got used to something that is completely redundant. What denotes the end of the line? If it's a constant what happens when someone's resolution is higher or their coding window is enlarged. Looks like clutter to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick :

Go to Eclipse's preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Code Templates

Then, you should be able to configure the comments appearance as you wish